# Why does the separator get changed by Path parentPath = Paths.get(strPath)?

Tags: java, path, ftp, nio

In my Windows app I want to delete a directory structure on the server with FTP using `SimpleFileVisitor<Path>`. It fails with "File not found" because in the code below the separator gets changed to backslash. Obviously, the server wants it to be forward slash. How can I make it stay as forward slash?

```
public class FTPTest {
static String server ;
static int port ;
static String user ;
static String pass; 
static FTPClient theFtpClient;
public FTPTest(){
    server = "nx.dnslinks.net";
    port = 21;
    user = "xxxx";
    pass = "#xxxxx"; 
    theFtpClient = new FTPClient();
}
static void deleteDirectoryWalkTree(Path path) throws IOException {
FileVisitor visitor = new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
      Files.delete(file);
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult visitFileFailed(Path file, IOException exc) throws IOException {
      Files.delete(file);
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
    @Override
    public FileVisitResult postVisitDirectory(Path dir, IOException exc) throws IOException {
      if (exc != null) {
        throw exc;
      }
      Files.delete(dir);
      return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
    }
};
    Files.walkFileTree(path, visitor);
}    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    FTPTest     theFTPTest = new FTPTest();
    Path Path = Paths.get("/httpdocs/manual-uploads/TestingFTPUtil/SubDir_1/SubDir_2");
    try {
        theFTPTest.deleteDirectoryWalkTree(Path);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(FTPTest.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I do not see, what your edit changes about your question, nor about a relevance of my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Path`/`Paths` classes are to isolate your code from the path syntax of the **local** operating system.

While you want to use the path for a **remote** FTP system, which may (does) use a different syntax. And mainly the same syntax, no matter on what local operating system your code happens to run.

So you should not use `Path`/`Paths` classes for FTP paths.

Comment: Well, that's interesting. Guess I can't use SimpleFileVisitor, or for that matter the alternative remove directory structure examples I've stumbled across. Any suggestions?

Comment: If your actual question is *"how to delete directory structure on FTP server"*, then post it as a question. I believe I have answered your current question (although it probably did you help you with your actual problem).

Comment: Right on both counts, Martin. Thanks. I found this,  which works! https://www.codejava.net/java-se/ftp/how-to-remove-a-non-empty-directory-on-a-ftp-server